# Custom font family with Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, fonts

I have a Material-UI React application that is up and running, and I am trying to add a new font to the application, but I am having some trouble.

After following the tutorial here, https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/, this is what the theme file looks like.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import NeoSansPro from './fonts/Neo-Sans-Pro.ttf';

const neoSansPro = {
  fontFamily: 'NeoSansPro',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontDisplay: 'swap',
  fontWeight: 400,
  src: `
    local('NeoSansPro'),
    url(${NeoSansPro}) format('ttf')
  `,
  unicodeRange: 'U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF',
};

const appTheme = createMuiTheme({
  ...
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'NeoSansPro, Arial',
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        '@font-face': [neoSansPro],
      },
    },
  },
  ...
});
```

Everywhere in the application the font is falling back to [Arial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial). Is there something I am missing in order to get the font `NeoSansPro working with my application?